# counterCache in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to display the total number of comments for a particular post in my blog. I have 'posts' and 'comments' tables in my database. Now, I am a bit confused about using counterCache. 
I first created a field in the 'posts database', namely, 'comment_count' and then I added the counterCache key in the post model.

```
var $hasMany = array('Comment'=>array('counterCache'=>true));
```

But this was not working. I also tried to go the other way round, i.e by creating a field in the cooments table and the adding the counterCache key to the model. But this was also not working. 
What am I missing here??Can I display the number of comments using  find('count')?? or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Today when i try to deleteAll(), the CounterCache didn't updated the count. and then i found how to make them friend.
http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/countercache-and-deleteall-how-to-make-them-friends/

You can use a inbuilt method $this->User->updateCounterCache(array('group_id' => 3));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're using `counterCache` correctly? `counterCache` and your own solution are somewhat unrelated.

> ## [3.7.4.1.1 counterCache - Cache your count()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/816/counterCache-Cache-your-count)
>
> This function helps you cache the count of related data. Instead of counting the records manually via find('count'), the model itself tracks any addition/deleting towards the associated $hasMany model and increases/decreases a dedicated integer field within the parent model table.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> class Image extends AppModel {
>     var $belongsTo = array(
>         'ImageAlbum' => array('counterCache' => true)
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> From now on, every time you add or remove a Image associated to ImageAlbum, the number within `ImageAlbum.image_count` is adjusted automatically.

In other words, it's designed so you *don't* have to `$this->Model->find('count')` manually and it'll only change when adding or deleting entries. In your case, you should add a `comment_count` field to your Post model (as you did), but then specify `belongsTo => Post, counterCache => true` in the Comment model. The reason being that whenever the *Comment* model changes (add/delete), it has to update the `counterCache` in the Post model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I dropped the idea of using counterCache after I got tired of it. The find('count') works perfectly for me. But, thanks for your answer. It has cleared my confusion about using counterCache :)

Comment: Is it possible to generate the counterCache retroactively, for records that already exist?

Comment: @IanMcIntyreSilber, yes, it does that for you

Answer (score 0):

you are using counterCache in correct way. But try to clear all files (not directories!) in /app/tmp/cache/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think counterCache can be used on a `$hasMany` relationship, only on `$belongsTo`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to initialize the CounterCache for existing data? I refactor my code to use it and indeed if I insert a record it'll update the data, but until then it shows 0 which will break other functionality.
I thought about writing a script to do the work, but thought there might be a trick?

Answer (score -6):

Guys, I figured it out. Write the following code in the view action of posts controller, set it and then echo it out in the view file. Works perfectly

```
$counts = $this->Post->Comment
>find('count',array('conditions'=>array('Comment.post_id'=>$post['Post']['id'])));
```